# Topology generated by complements of subbasic open sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau$ be a topology on a set $X$, and let $S \subseteq \tau$ be a subbase. Write $\widehat{S} = \{A^c \mid A \in S\}$ for the complements of the sets in $S$, and let $\widehat{\tau}$ denote the topology generated by $\widehat{S}$. Is there any connection between $\tau$, $S$ and $\widehat\tau$? Is there a name for $\widehat\tau$? I expect that in general $\widehat{\tau}$ depends on the choice of the subbase $S$ (but I have not been able to verify this).

I can see that any $\widehat\tau$-open set is a union of $\tau$-closed sets. If $\tau$ and $\widehat\tau$ are both Alexandrov (e.g. if $X$ is finite) then a set is $\widehat\tau$-open iff it is $\tau$-closed. Is there anything that can be said more generally? I am particularly interested in whether there is any link between the constructible sets of $\tau$ and $\widehat\tau$.

Comment: Don’t you mean $\mathcal S \subseteq \tau$? I should be a subbase for $\tau$ I suppose.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Yes, thanks. Have edited the question.